# WSO2 ERROR org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor cannot be found by synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v143

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

It is not cleare to me why i am getting this error ?

The error happaned when i runned my ESB integrator WSO2 6.6.0 for Windows and try test my .car app.

As you can see the logs belowe EI can not to determine the path to the synapse.xml. Maybe somebody can me to explane how i can fix this problem
[image]

Belowe is my logs

```
Starting WSO2 Carbon (in unsupported JDK)
[ERROR] CARBON is supported only on JDK 1.7, 1.8, 9, 10 and 11
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\ENTERP~1\6683E8~1.0\bin\..
[2024-02-26 17:20:35,975]  INFO {org.ops4j.pax.logging.spi.support.EventAdminConfigurationNotifier} - Sending Event Admin nofification (configuration successful) to org/ops4j/pax/logging/Configuration
[2024-02-26 17:20:36,413]  INFO {org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender} - No quiesce support is available, so blueprint components will not participate in quiesce operations
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,319]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,327]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Operating System : Windows 10 10.0, amd64
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,327]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Home        : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\jre
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,328]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Version     : 1.8.0_271
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,328]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.271-b09,Oracle Corporation
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,328]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Carbon Home      : C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\ENTERP~1\6683E8~1.0\bin\..
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,329]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Temp Dir    : C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\ENTERP~1\6683E8~1.0\bin\..\wso2\tmp
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,329]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - User             : zhurenko-ym, ru-RU, Europe/Helsinki
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,479]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.internal.DefaultCryptoProviderComponent} - 'CryptoService.Secret' property has not been set. 'org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider' won't be registered as an internal crypto provider. Please set the secret if the provider needs to be registered.
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,498]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.google.tokengen.servlet.internal.GoogleTokenGenDSComponent} - Activating GoogleTokengen DS component
[2024-02-26 17:20:38,635]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS} - Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2024-02-26 17:20:42,236]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} - Configured Registry in 55ms
[2024-02-26 17:20:42,287]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} - Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
[2024-02-26 17:20:53,097]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient} - Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
[2024-02-26 17:20:53,223]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} - Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,076]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} - User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,077]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} - User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,810]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender} - JMS Sender started
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,812]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender} - JMS Transport Sender initialized...
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,813]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportSender} - VFS Sender started
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,850]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} - Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,885]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} - Pass-through HTTP Sender started...
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,886]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender} - MAILTO Sender started
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,893]  WARN {javax.mail} - expected resource not found: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,896]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} - Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,904]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender} - Pass-through HTTPS Sender started...
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,927] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager} - Error setting up connection factory : myTopicConnectionFactory org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Cannot acquire JNDI context, JMS Connection factory :
                TopicConnectionFactory or default destination : null for JMS CF : myTopicConnectionFactory using : {java.naming.factory.initial=
                org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, java.naming.provider.url=conf/jndi.properties, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=
                TopicConnectionFactory}
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.initJMSConnectionFactory(JMSConnectionFactory.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.<init>(JMSConnectionFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager.loadConnectionFactoryDefinitions(JMSConnectionFactoryManager.java:89)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager.<init>(JMSConnectionFactoryManager.java:76)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hash table. [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class
                org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory not found]
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:491)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.initJMSConnectionFactory(JMSConnectionFactory.java:174)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class
                org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory not found
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder.classForName(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:1208)
...
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,958] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager} - Error setting up connection factory : default org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Cannot acquire JNDI context, JMS Connection factory :
                QueueConnectionFactory or default destination : null for JMS CF : default using : {java.naming.factory.initial=
                org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, java.naming.provider.url=conf/jndi.properties, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=
                QueueConnectionFactory}
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.initJMSConnectionFactory(JMSConnectionFactory.java:188)
        ...
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hash table. [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class
                org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory not found]
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:491)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681)
     ...
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,968] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryManager} - Error setting up connection factory : myQueueConnectionFactory org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Cannot acquire JNDI context, JMS Connection factory :
                QueueConnectionFactory or default destination : null for JMS CF : myQueueConnectionFactory using : {java.naming.factory.initial=
                org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, java.naming.provider.url=conf/jndi.properties, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType=queue, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=
                QueueConnectionFactory}
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSConnectionFactory.initJMSConnectionFactory(JMSConnectionFactory.java:188)
        ...
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hash table. [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class
                org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory not found]
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:491)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        ...
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,974]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener} - JMS Transport Receiver/Listener initialized...
[2024-02-26 17:21:08,997]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener} - Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
[2024-02-26 17:21:09,003] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.config.SourceConfiguration} - Error creating WSDL processor java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
            org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor cannot be found by synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v143
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
        ...
[2024-02-26 17:21:09,068] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager} - Couldn't initialize the httptransport listener org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error creating WSDL processor
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.config.SourceConfiguration.handleException(SourceConfiguration.java:245)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
            org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor cannot be found by synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v143
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
        ...
[2024-02-26 17:21:09,084]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLListener} - Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
[2024-02-26 17:21:09,090] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.config.SourceConfiguration} - Error creating WSDL processor java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
            org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor cannot be found by synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v143
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.config.SourceConfiguration.createHttpGetProcessor(SourceConfiguration.java:224)
        ...
[2024-02-26 17:21:09,095] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.engine.ListenerManager} - Couldn't initialize the httpstransport listener org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error creating WSDL processor
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.config.SourceConfiguration.handleException(SourceConfiguration.java:245)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.config.SourceConfiguration.createHttpGetProcessor(SourceConfiguration.java:226)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.config.SourceConfiguration.build(SourceConfiguration.java:135)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpListener.init(PassThroughHttpListener.java:176)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
            org.wso2.carbon.mediation.transport.handlers.PassThroughNHttpGetProcessor cannot be found by synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v143
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
        ...
[2024-02-26 17:21:14,623]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInterceptor} - Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {super-tenant}
[2024-02-26 17:21:15,167]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} - Repository       : C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\ENTERP~1\6683E8~1.0\bin\../repository/deployment/server/
[2024-02-26 17:21:15,250]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.eager.TenantLoadingConfig} - Using tenant lazy loading policy...
[2024-02-26 17:21:15,268]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} - Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
[2024-02-26 17:21:15,444]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.rule.kernel.internal.ds.RuleEngineConfigDS} - Successfully registered the Rule Config service
[2024-02-26 17:21:16,258]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} - Starting ESB...
[2024-02-26 17:21:16,287]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} - Initializing Apache Synapse...
[2024-02-26 17:21:16,292]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory} - Using Synapse home : C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\ENTERP~1\6683E8~1.0\.
[2024-02-26 17:21:16,293] FATAL {org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory} - The synapse.xml location .\.\
        repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs\default doesn't exist
[2024-02-26 17:21:16,299] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer} - Couldn't initialize the ESB... org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: The synapse.xml location .\.\
        repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs\default doesn't exist
        at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.handleFatal(SynapseControllerFactory.java:121)
        at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.validatePath(SynapseControllerFactory.java:113)
        at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.validate(SynapseControllerFactory.java:88)
        at org.apache.synapse.SynapseControllerFactory.createSynapseController(SynapseControllerFactory.java:44)
        at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.init(ServerManager.java:104)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:370)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:170)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence.service.InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.activate(InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:234)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1077)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4868)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService.startInternal(ExtendedStandardService.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.start(CarbonTomcat.java:113)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager$1.run(ServerManager.java:167)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[2024-02-26 17:21:17,305]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} - Mgt Console URL  : https://10.49.31.17:9443/carbon/
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has encountered this problem or something similar - first of all, you need to look at your config files and check the following things as shown below. There should be no blank spaces between the end of the tag and the string parameter in it:

- it is wrong
  [image]
- it is right
  [image]

Be careful and good luck everyobdy